# Fonts are not correctly loaded in wine

Tags: 18.04, wine, fonts, playonlinux, winetricks

You can see my problem in image that I attach to my question

[screenshot from my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWv8y.png)

I run pes 2017 setting.exe in playonlinux. My wine version is 3.20
and this my log file in playonlinux :

```
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0030:err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\quartz.dll"
0030:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {cda42200-bd88-11d0-bd4e-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x1
wine: configuration in '/home/pash/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/PES2017' has been updated.
003b:err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
0009:err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\dxdiagn.dll"
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {a65b8071-3bfe-4213-9a5b-491da4461ca7} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0009:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0009:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0009:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
```

Comment: have you tried using winetricks in order to add corefonts to your wine? corefonts is an often-required package.

Comment: yes.i install corefonts and tahoma font too but problem not solve